# Is "config" abbreviation of "configuration"?

Tags: word-request, abbreviations

I'm learning English. I make a system with configuration module.

Is appropriate **config**  instead of **configuration**?

Comment: Yes, but only in certain contexts, usually technical situations.   Computer people use "config files" all the time.

Comment: A small correction: You have written "I learning English."  Debe ser "I **am** learning English", como "Yo **estoy** aprendiendo inglés", y no "Yo aprendiendo inglés."  :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is correct.

Config = configuration. The shortened usage is especially common in computing.

Comment: I suspect that the shortened form would not be recognised by many people outside computing. But then the technical meaning of "configuration" will not be known to them either.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the config can be used as the clipped term for configuration. Although the shortened may be strange for some groups of people, that is to say, the usage of the form solely depends on the situation of context by the user and that is the way of communication. In fact, we are free to create new ways as our language system let us do in this way; the productivity of language can not bind us to be stagnate. We are able to make new words, use them in different situations and devote them to specific class and finally as an entry in a dictionary. All words should be said to give familiarity in terms of usage frequency to be accepted by people.